# Sequence/series printing in java

Tags: java, loops, series

I want to write a code in Java which inputs any integer value by the user and gives a output as sum of consecutive numbers=input. All possibilities.

**Eg**

**Input**
15
**Output**

1. 7+8
2. 4+5+6
3. 1+2+3+4×5

Comment: So what have you come up with yourself? Where's the code?

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens 
Now see it.
Actually i am asking for the code.

Comment: Example 3 should be `1+2+3+4+5` not `1+2+3+4x5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have tried to come up with any algorithm by yourself, you should find out that brutal algorithm is not quite possible to solve this problem. I assume what you need is an algorithm instead of the code itself.

Let's assume all integers in the range `[a,b]` summing up to your input. So you will end up with this equation `(b+a) (b-a+1) / 2 = input`. In your case where input = 15, `(b+a)` and `(b-a+1)` would be two of the factors of `input * 2`, which is 30.

Therefore, there are four possibilities for `(a,b)`

1. (b+a, b-a+1) = (30, 1), so (a,b)=(15,15)
2. (b+a, b-a+1) = (15, 2), so (a,b)=(7,8)
3. (b+a, b-a+1) = (10, 3), so (a,b)=(4,6)
4. (b+a, b-a+1) = (6, 5), so (a,b)=(1,5)

In summary, this problem is essentially to ask you how to factor a number.